# How could add hidden files to my find candidates on linux

Tags: linux, shell, find

I know I could find a file or directory with command

```
find ./ -name 'filename'
```

but this only searches in the un-hidden files, how could I also search in the hidden files ?

Comment: `find` does _not_ ignore hidden files. Your command will find `filename` in both hidden and non-hidden folders; however, since `filename` does not begin with the dot, it is by definition not a hidden file itself. Can you describe a specific situation that you are trying to solve? The generalisation is obscuring the meaning of the question.

Comment: Have a try using just `find ./`, so without filtering for the name. You will see that the `find` utility does not care if a file is hidden or not.

Answer (score 1):

If the name is the same:

```
find ./ -name '*filename'
```

Another way to include new rules in the find query would it be:

```
find ./  -name "filename" -o -name ".filename"
```

-o ( or )
-a ( and )

[* Reference 1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50612/how-to-combine-2-name-conditions-in-find)